# How to watch Netflix from Europe with an US account and without VPN

Tags: internet, vpn, netflix

When I open the [Netflix website](http://www.netflix.com/) from Europe I get: "Sorry, Netflix is not available in your country yet." However, there is still the *Member sign in* button.

If Netflix is blocked in Europe altogether why would they allow logging in for members?

I know I can use a VPN to watch Netflix, but I am asking if this is possible only with US accounts and without a VPN. I have a good Internet connection, but still I am not sure if streaming would be possible through VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use http://tunlr.org:

*Do you want to stream video or audio from U.S.-based on-demand Internet streaming media providers but can't get in on the fun because you're living outside the U.S.? Fear not, you have come to the right place. Tunlr lets you stream content from sites like Netflix, Hulu, MTV, CBS, ABC, Pandora and more to your Mac or PC. Want to watch Netflix or HuluPlus on your iPad, AppleTV or XBox 360 even though you're not in the U.S.? Tunlr lets you do this.*

It is quiet easy to set up. just follow the instructions under:

http://tunlr.net/get-started/

The traffic is not diverted through a tunlr server so you can even enjoy HD content if your internet connection is fast enough. For more details on how it works visit the [tunlr FAQ](http://tunlr.net/faq/)

Comment: Wow, thank you, this looks really promising. I set it up and now when I visit Netflix I no longer see "Sorry, Netflix is not available in your country yet." I am really curious what's the technology behind this.

Comment: As of October 2013, tunlr.org does not exist, but http://tunlr.net/ does. Seems they changed domain...

Comment: tunlr.net also stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Proxmate](http://proxmate.dave.cx/) if you are on Chrome | Firefox

#### How does it work?

It detects if you are visiting one of the websites below. If yes, it enables itself and tells the site, that you are within the U.S. Otherwise the extension is quiet. The rest works exactly the same way as @Paul Hay explained in his answer for media hint.

> ProxMate uses a wide proxy server network to load only the important bits of a website. You get all the advantages of using a proxy, without using a proxy!

#### Which sites are supported

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is already solved, but there's a browser add-on for this purpose as well called "Mediahint". Uses a proxy when the site tries to determine your location and then uses your own bandwidth from then on, allowing you to get the best quality your connection allows.

Answer (score 1):

Mediahint and Tunlr are good free options. However Mediahint is browser only and Tunlr requires that your ISP has been added to the whitelist in order to use the service. Commercial alternatives like [Unlocator](http://unlocator.com) works with more services and are free to try.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never! You can also use [Cocoon](http://getcocoon.com) to view Netflix from overseas - the proxy IP is U.S.-based and it is pretty fast too :)

For Firefox and iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoon works fine as a VPN for Chrome on iOS but Netflix requires that you use their iOS app and it doesn't work thru Cocoon.